# how to properly install stylecop?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, stylecop, windows-7-x64

Well i downloaded the newest version, then installed, checked to instal entire files on local drive. I restarted VS2010 and rerun it. Unfortunatelly i can't find in menu > tools anything with should be connected with stylecop ( as in tutorial "how to use stylecop"). I am using x64 Windows7.
I really really don't know how to to use it.

Look: I click inside code, white field and i see only this:
[image]

Comment: Which version did you download (the latest is 4.5.13)? Do you have C:\Program Files\StyleCop 4.5 folder? Do you have StyleCop displayed in Help / About menu in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you using one of the Visual Studio Express products?  If so, you will not see UI integration of StyleCop since the VS Express edition does not support integration of add-ins and packages like StyleCop.

If you are using Express, you could still run StyleCop, but this will require using either MSBuild integration or a pre- or post- build event.

Comment: i didnt doticed that express will suck

Comment: This link shows how to integrate StyleCop into Visual Studio C# Express 2010. Its warnings will only show when there are zero compiler errors: http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Running%20StyleCop%20in%20VS2005%20or%20VS%20Express

Answer (score 11):

1) Download StyleCop from [here](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/releases/view/44839#DownloadId=120689)

2) Close all Visual Studio instances

3) Install StyleCop

4) Open Visual Studio, Right click inside code file and you could see `Run StyleCop` Option

Comment: i did it, and no "Run StyleCop"

Comment: You have to Right-Click on the code-file in the Solution Explorer (and not inside your code-file) to select "Run StyleCop" option.
If you right-click inside your code-file, all you can see is "Exclude from StyleCop" option"
Hope this helps.

Comment: "Run StyleCop" option will not be available with visual studio express editions

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is possible to use StyleCop with Express edition. [Here is how](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Running%20StyleCop%20in%20VS2005%20or%20VS%20Express).